# Apache flink partitions

Tags: java, jvm, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have been researching on flink. I have doubt regarding memory management in flink. How is the memory managed in flink. Is there any similar feature like "blocks in spark" also in flink? Please let me know if there are good places to read about the memory management in flink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink implements its own memory management which is called managed memory. Managed memory solves problems you usually have when using the JVM's heap memory like garbage collection, memory layout and hard to predict object sizes. With managed memory Flink is able to gracefully spill to disk when the data grows and it avoids long garbage collection pauses/reduces garbage collection pressure, because the managed memory section is not subject to GC.

You can find further information about Flink's managed memory [here](https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/05/11/Juggling-with-Bits-and-Bytes.html) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=53741525).